# Button won't have the same width as the column it's in

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, grid

Im trying to make my button have the same width as the column it's in. I have succeeded with this before on my website, but this time it just wont work... 
The issue is appearing on the following link; http://haagmedia.dk/klf/fanzone.php 
The two buttons is in two separate columns, and its both I want to have the full width. 
All help is appreciated :)!

HTML

```
<div class="knap2 row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                <a href="#" class="fanknap" alt="Fanzone">FANZONE</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                <a href="#" class="fanknap" alt="Støttemedlem">STØTTEMEDLEM</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.fanknap {
    background-color: #208AF0;
    border: 2px solid #208AF0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `display:block;` to your buttons CSS.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/fhfhrc78/

Comment: Love it, when it is so straight forward! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
.fanknap {
    /* Other styles... */
    display:block
}
```

to your css should fix the issue. Alternatively you could play around with the padding until you get what you need. However, I strongly recommend the former.

Hope it helps!